# Uploading via HTTP POST to a cloud file hosting

Tags: java, web-services, hosting, cloud, cloud-hosting

For my Android application, I need to upload videos in a wide variety size to a cloud system not to exhaust my own server. I don't want to change my code so much. So I am looking for a way to post a file through HTTP web service. Do you know what is the best alternative for this?

Comment: It depends on what your hosting provider offers. And, anyway, why not FTP?

Comment: ftp is also possible. My main concern is to be able to use it on Android. Which cloud do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). I will allow you to formulate the POST request. I am not an Android Developer, but judging the search results, it is available for you to use.